# Make doesn't resolve outdated dependencies as I would expect it to

Tags: java, makefile, dependencies

I am currently working on a Java project which I chose to compile with Make (please don't judge me).

Here is the Makefile I finally came up with: (I am compiling on Windows)

```
rwildcard = $(strip $(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2)))

SRCDIR := src
RESOURCESDIR := resources
LIBDIR := lib
BUILDDIR := build

SRCFILES := $(call rwildcard,$(SRCDIR)/,*.java)
CLASSPATH := $(subst $(eval) ,;,$(wildcard $(LIBDIR)/*.jar))
TARGET := target.jar

.PHONY: default install clean

default: $(TARGET)

$(BUILDDIR): $(SRCFILES)
    @if not exist $(BUILDDIR) mkdir $(BUILDDIR)
    javac -d $(BUILDDIR) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -sourcepath $(SRCDIR) $(SRCFILES)
    copy /y $(RESOURCESDIR) $(BUILDDIR)

$(TARGET): $(BUILDDIR)
    jar -cvf $(TARGET) -C $(BUILDDIR) .

install: $(TARGET)
    copy /y $(TARGET) "C:/path/to/installation/directory/"

clean:
    @if exist $(BUILDDIR) rmdir /s /q $(BUILDDIR)
    @if exist $(TARGET) del /q $(TARGET)
```

N.B.: in case you wonder, the first line defines a recursive `wildcard` function for finding all .java files.

So the idea is to have one rule which compiles all source files at once and copies the resource files into a `build` folder, and another rule which creates the .jar target archive from that folder. You can ignore the other rules.

Now here's my problem: if I run `make target.jar` (after having modified at least one source file), the first rule is executed as a dependency, so I see the sources being compiled, but the second rule never executes, and my .jar archive is not updated. I have to run `make clean` for the .jar to be rebuilt.

There must be something I'm doing wrong about chained dependencies, please help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a target dependent on the timestamp of a directory is a risky thing (no offense meant: you should know what you do if you do that ;) )
In your case it is definitely unclean design: your target depends on intermediary files, not on the place these are stored to. Your compilation process does not update the timestamp of $(BUILDDIR) and therefore make sees no need to execute the recipes of $(TARGET) as its prerequisite isn't more recent. You will need to add your `.class` files to the prerequisite list plus rules for these, including the $(BUILDDIR) as order-only prerequisite.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought the build directory's timestamp would be updated when javac updates the files inside it... Thanks :D